# How to move a sprite without decimals in its position

Tags: xna, detection, pixel, move, xna-4.0

Currently, my game using some pixel detections.
For exemple, for sprites, i retrieve the pixel of its position.
When i move it, the position values have some decimals like :

```
thePixel = new vector(position.X, position.Y);
//thePixel = (52.2451, 635.2642)
```

so i have to Round These values

```
thePixel = new vector((float)Math.Round(position.X, 0), (float)Math.Round(position.Y, 0));
//thePixel = (52, 635)
```

I would like to know if there are some other ways to get perfect position (means, without decimal) without Rounding them.
Is it maybe a moving method problem ?

Thx for reading, hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really get around the need to round your values, but you can make it a lot nicer to code by using an extension method:

```
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static Vector2 Floor(this Vector2 vector)
    {
        return new Vector2((float)Math.Floor(vector.X), (float)Math.Floor(vector.Y));
    }
}
```

(As you can see, personally I prefer `Floor` to `Round`. I also have one for `Ceiling`.)

Then you can just use it like this:

```
HandleCollision(position.Floor());
```

---

Of course, if you're doing per-pixel collision detection - your collision maths should probably be integer-based (not stored as `float` in a `Vector2`). You could use `Point`. Turns out I have an extension method for that too:

```
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static Point AsXnaPoint(this Vector2 v)
    {
        return new Point((int)v.X, (int)v.Y);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
HandleCollision(position.AsXNAPoint());
```

Or possibly:

```
HandleCollision(position.Floor().AsXNAPoint());
```

Comment: As usual, thx Andrew.
Btw, you are part of the people who made me wanna create my own video game (with your "Dark" game, and some tips you gave me).
Thx again